# Skip AccountsSettingsPane and use logged in user

Tags: c#, authentication, uwp

Is there a way to skip the account selection in the AccountsSettingsPane and just use the currently logged in user instead, without having to select an account ?

Comment: In general, you need check if it has token value in the localsetting storage, and if the value is  not expire, you have no need show  AccountsSettingsPane again.

Comment: I meant like completely skipping even the first time account selection, or is that not possible ? Like using the account you are currently logged into windows with.

Comment: I have to say that is impossible. it only support  select manually or cancel selection.